# Javascript Append Icon to Field

Tags: javascript, html, onload

I have a field on my page with an id of orit_c_discountrate i need to add an image after this field with an onlcick to call another Javascript function named UpdateQuotedPrice I have written this below:

```
function AddPercentImage(){
    var img = document.createElement('IMG');
    img.setAttribute('src', 'Themes/Img/default/icons/recent_order.gif');
    img.onclick = function(){
            UpdateQuotedPrice();
        }
    //This is the line that errors
    document.getElementById('orit_c_discountrate').appendChild(img)
}
```

and using this attachEvent

```
window.attachEvent("onload",AddPercentImage);
```

however I get the following error in the console

> SCRIPT65535: Unexpected call to method or property access.

Element:

```
<input name="orit_c_discountrate" class="EDIT" id="orit_c_discountrate" type="text" size="4" maxLength="4"/>
```

can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: which line of code causes this error ?

Comment: sorry my bad, the appendChild is erroring

Comment: Works here > http://jsfiddle.net/eNnWv/ <- no problems (apart from the image doesnt exist !!)... are you sure you have an element with an id of `orit_c_discountrate`. Can you include your HTML ?

Comment: You cannot append a child to an input ....

Comment: Oh ok what are my options then?

Comment: Incidentally, it looks like you're trying to do web development in Internet Explorer. While IE has come a long way recently it's still not great for developers, as evidenced by the very unuseful error message "Unexpected call to method or property access." Consider using Chrome or Firefox to develop in, as the developer tools in both are excellent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot append an image as a child element of an `input` ... you could wrap you input within a `<span>` (or another element such as a `div`) and append the image to that .. for example :

HTML :

```
<span><input name="orit_c_discountrate" class="EDIT" id="orit_c_discountrate" type="text" size="4" maxLength="4"/></span>​
```

JavaScript:

```
function AddPercentImage() {
    var img = document.createElement('IMG');
    img.setAttribute('src', 'Themes/Img/default/icons/recent_order.gif');
    img.onclick = function() {
        UpdateQuotedPrice();
    };
    //This is the line that errors
    document.getElementById('orit_c_discountrate').parentNode.appendChild(img);
}
```

[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PWb2z/)